# Is there any way that Client responses Server in SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

My server side code:

```cs
var _identity = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(aa => aa.serverId == serverId);
var rsp = Clients.Client(_identity.connectionId).RcvSendToUser(message);
```

My client side code:

```cs
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
_hub.On("RcvSendToUser", x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

When the client receives the `message`, is it possible that client response a string value to the server side? If possible, how to modify my code on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a new method in your server side hub and call it from the client.

Add this method to the hub in server:

```cs
public void AcknowledgeServer(String ack) {
  // Do your stuff.
}
```

And modify the client code a little bit:

```cs
_hub.On("RcvSendToUser", x => {
  Console.WriteLine(x);

  // Now call the server method with the string value.
  _hub.Invoke("AcknowledgeServer", "Your string to server")
});
```

Comment: You could wrap @Xmindz answer in a Task and complete it in a nonblocking way without the caller need extra code